# Tap gesture is not working in custom cell view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, custom-cell

I am having a custom cell. I added a `UILabel` in my cell and added a tap gesture to it. It was supposed to work but it is not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = chunk;
    label.userInteractionEnabled = isLink;

    if (isLink)
    {

        // 5. Set tap gesture for this clickable text:
        SEL selectorAction = isTermsOfServiceLink ? @selector(termsPressed) : @selector(privacyPressed);
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                     action:selectorAction];
        [label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    }

    // 6. Lay out the labels so it forms a complete sentence again:

    // If this word doesn't fit at end of this line, then move it to the next
    // line and make sure any leading spaces are stripped off so it aligns nicely:

    [label sizeToFit];

    if (self.privacyLbl.frame.size.width < wordLocation.x + label.bounds.size.width)
    {
        wordLocation.x = 0.0;                       // move this word all the way to the left...
        wordLocation.y += label.frame.size.height;  // ...on the next line

        // And trim of any leading white space:
        NSRange startingWhiteSpaceRange = [label.text rangeOfString:@"^\\s*#"
                                                            options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
        if (startingWhiteSpaceRange.location == 0)
        {
            label.text = [label.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:startingWhiteSpaceRange
                                                             withString:@""];
            [label sizeToFit];
        }
    }

    // Set the location for this label:
    label.frame = CGRectMake(wordLocation.x,
                             wordLocation.y-20,
                             label.frame.size.width,
                             label.frame.size.height);

    label.text  = @"";        
    [self.privacyLbl addSubview:label];
```

My methods:

```
-(IBAction)termsPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate voorWardenButtonPressed];
}

-(IBAction)privacyPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate privacyButtonPressed];
}
```

I have tried simple methods rather than `IBAction`. Still it does not detect tap on labels.

Comment: Add following code `// 5. Set tap gesture for this clickable text:` `tapGesture .delegate = self`

Comment: Well, I am using same code in viewContoller and it is working fine. I set delegate for tab gesture but still it is not working.

Comment: Make sure you have set `userInteractionEnabled` property to **TRUE**.

Comment: Yes it is true. I have debugged it and it is always true

Comment: Might be your Tap Gesture and UITableView/UICollectionView didSelect method are being conflicted

Comment: I think problem comes from table view, that also has tap gestures attached (for cell selection). You can try to play with shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer or just add transparent UIButton over your label / use UIButton instead of UILabel as @stosha suggested


  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

Comment: @f3n1kc : Yeah, that is a good Solution

Comment: this is what i have in my didSelect method:
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

Comment: Yes you are right and I have done that too. I am also surprised that why it is not working. I have done this many times but still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to enable `userInteractionEnabled` flag associated to your label

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
SEL selectorAction = isTermsOfServiceLink ? @selector(termsPressed) : @selector(privacyPressed);
```

on to this:

```
SEL selectorAction = isTermsOfServiceLink ? @selector(termsPressed:) : @selector(privacyPressed:);
```

Comment: Tried this but still not detecting the tap

Comment: Try to change label to custom button and remove gesture recognizer

Comment: I tried that too but still it does not work. It works fine if I do it in viewController